# How to sort comma separated words in Vim

Tags: sorting, vim

In Python code, I frequently run into import statements like this:

```
from foo import ppp, zzz, abc
```

Is there any Vim trick, like `:sort` for lines, to sort to this:

```
from foo import abc, ppp, zzz
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, there is:

```
%s/import\s*\zs.*/\=join(sort(split(submatch(0), '\s*,\s*')),', ')
```

The key elements are:

- [`:h :substitute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3asubstitute)
- [`:h /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5czs)
- [`:h s/\=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)
- [`:h submatch()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29)
- [`:h sort()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#sort%28%29)
- [`:h join()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#join%28%29)
- [`:h split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split%28%29)

To answer the comment, if you want to apply the substitution on a visual selection, it becomes:

```
'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V\@!/\=join(sort(split(submatch(0), '\s*,\s*')), ', ')
```

The new key elements are this time:

- [`:h /\%V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%25V) that says the next character matched shall belong to the visual selection
- [`:h /\@!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%40%21) that I use, in order to express (combined with `\%V`), that the next character shall **not** belong to the visual selection. That next character isn't kept in the matched expression.

BTW, we can also use [`s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#s) and [`i_CTRL-R_=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dR_%3d)  interactively, or put it in a mapping (here triggered on `µ`):

```
:xnoremap µ s<c-r>=join(sort(split(@", '\s*,\s*')), ', ')<cr><esc>
```

Comment: Can I visual mark the comma separated list portion and apply this operation on that? That might be more general since I could apply that on other types of Python code (like elements of an actual list).

Comment: In my system (Debian 10), typing ":h sub-replace-\=" has given a better result than ":h s/\=". It should be the same, but...

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can do the following steps:

1. Move the words you want to sort to the next line:

   > ```
   > from foo import 
   > ppp, zzz, abc
   > ```
2. Add a comma at the end of the words list:

   > ```
   > from foo import 
   > ppp, zzz, abc,
   > ```
3. Select the word list for example with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. Now hit <kbd>:</kbd> and then enter `!xargs -n1 | sort | xargs`. It should look like this:

   > ```
   > :'<,'>!xargs -n1 | sort | xargs
   > ```

   Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   > ```
   > from foo import 
   > abc, ppp, zzz,
   > ```
4. Now remove the trailing comma and merge the word list back to the original line (for example with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>).

   > ```
   > from foo import abc, ppp, zzz
   > ```

---

There are Vim plugins, which might be useful to you:

- [AdvancedSorters : Sorting of certain areas or by special needs.](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958)

Comment: AdvancedSorters plugin looks very useful. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AshwinNanjappa I'm glad I could help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a fast way to sort comma separated lists, in general, e.g.

```
    relationships = {
        'project', 'freelancer', 'task', 'managers', 'team'
    }
```

My habit was to search/replace spaces with newlines and invoke shell sort but that's such a pain.

I ended up finding Chris Toomey's `sort-motion` plugin, which is just the ticket: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-sort-motion. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try vim-isort ? https://github.com/fisadev/vim-isort

I use that and vim-yapf-format for beautify the code :) https://github.com/pignacio/vim-yapf-format

Answer (score 0):

Select the comma-separated text in visual mode, <kbd>:</kbd>, and run this command:

```
'<,'>!tr ',' '\n' | sort -f | paste -sd ','
```

<sup>-tip [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665195/how-to-sort-comma-separated-values-in-bash#comment82290597_47665195)</sup>

Comment: macos/bsd flavour of paste complains with `usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...`  . It requires a `-` at the end `!tr ',' '\n' | sort -f | paste -sd ','` to make sure it's working on stdin