# How to sort comma separated values in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, sorting

I have some numbers like

`7, 15, 6, 2, -9`

I want to sort it like this in bash(from command line or either a script file)

`-9, 2, 6, 7, 15`

How can I do this? I am unable to get this using sort command.

Comment: Do you need spaces after commas? Without them it's just: `tr ',' '\n' <<< "7,15,6,2,-9" | sort -n | paste -sd ','`

Comment: @PesaThe: If comma-space is required, all that's necessary is `| sed 's/,/, /g'` after your command line. And the spaces in the input can be `tr`'d away too.  The `paste` does the critical job of not appending a comma after the last number.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
echo "7, 15, 6, 2, -9" | sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g' | sort -n | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'
```

1. `sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g'`: For splitting string into lines by comma.
2. `sort -n`: Then you can use sort by number
3. `tr '\n' ','`: Covert newline separator back to comma.
4. `sed 's/.$//'`: Removing tailing comma.

Not elegant enough, but it should work :p

Comment: Nice!  I'm intrigued that you didn't use `tr` to replace the commas (and blanks) with newlines: `echo "7, 15, 6, 2, -9" | tr -s ', ' '\n\n' | sort -n | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'`.  The `paste -sd ','` alternative suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665195/how-to-sort-comma-separated-values-in-bash#comment82290597_47665195) is useful instead of the second `tr` and the `sed`.  And POSIX demands a file name for `paste`, so portable code would use `paste -s -d ',' -` — GNU `paste` is more sensible, but BSD (macOS) `paste` adheres exactly to POSIX on that.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ s='7, 15, 6, 2, -9'
$ echo "$s" | perl -F',\h*' -lane 'print join ", ", sort {$a <=> $b} @F'
-9, 2, 6, 7, 15
$ echo "$s" | perl -F',\h*' -lane 'print join ", ", sort {$b <=> $a} @F'
15, 7, 6, 2, -9
```

- `-F',\h*'` use `,` and optional space/tab as field separator

  - see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for explanation of command line options
- `sort {$a <=> $b} @F` sort the array numerically, in ascending order... use `sort {$b <=> $a} @F'` for descending order
- `join ", "` tells how to join the array elements before passing on to print

Answer (score 0):

To summarize answers and comments, this works and maintains spaces:

`echo "7, 15, 6, 2, -9" | sed -e $'s:,:\\\n:g' | sort -n | paste -sd ',' - | sed 's:,:, :g'`

Note that you may be able to get away with `sed -e 's:,:\n:g'` instead of the first `sed` call. This works on my system running `bash` version 4.2.46 with `sed` version 4.2.2. To remove the spaces (or if they're unnecessary), remove the final `sed` call and pipe.