# How to sort ROW in a line in BASH

Tags: bash

Most sorting available in bash or linux terminal commands are about sorting a field (column). I couldn't figure out how to sort a row of three number, e.g. "1, 3, 2". I want it from left to right are small to large, like "1,2,3" or vice versa.

So input would be like line="5, 3, 10". After being sorted, the output will be sorted_line="3,5,10".

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665195/how-to-sort-comma-separated-values-in-bash

Comment: substitute the row separator for a newline -> sort lines -> substitute newlines for row separator

Comment: Is the input separated by comma or comma-space? You have both in your question.

Comment: The solution from the link works. Thanks Ben. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `asort` works for `gawk` not general `awk`. So here is another solution for a file, a.txt

```
gawk -F, '{split($0, w); s=""; for(i=1; i<=asort(w); i++) s=s w[i] ","; print s }' a.txt | sed 's/,$//'
```

sample file, a.txt is

```
1,5,7,2
8,1,3,4
9,7,8,2
```

result,

```
1,2,5,7
1,3,4,8
2,7,8,9
```

Comment: AS you can see in my answer **asort** works in **awk**.

Comment: that is possible it works on one environment, but not in all env

Comment: @MatiasBarrios Yes, if your awk is GNU awk. POSIX requires not sorting function in awk.

Comment: Would need to install the gawk package on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way :

```
echo "6 5,4,9 1,3 2,10,7 8" | awk '{ split($0,arr,"(,| )") ; asort(arr); exit; } END{ for ( i=1; i <= length(arr) ; i++ ) { print arr[i]} }'
```

I am using a regex as a delimiter so it can be comma or space separated.

Hope it helps!